Exiting the U.S. through Canada (exit stamp U.S.)
I traveled from Germany to the U.S. under the Visa Waiver Program with an ESTA. When I passed through immigration, I got an entry stamp with the current date on it.
Now knowing that the U.S. doesn't have exit controls, I known that if I would fly back from there the airline would notify them that I left. But what about, if I'm going to Canada via a land border and then fly back to Germany from there?
How does the U.S. know I left? Do I get an entry stamp in Canada and if so, is that enough to prove (in case of a later reentry with a new ESTA) that I left the U.S. in time.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Simon
